# Where from can I catch the copenhagen zoo snake bus?

Tags: public-transport, buses, copenhagen, zoos

Can anyone tell me where I can catch the copenhagen zoo snake bus in order to go to the zoo. Is it possible to catch it someplace close to the center ?

[image: snake bus]

Comment: The correct word for "where from" is *whence*. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The depicted bus is not a special "snake line", but an ordinary bus on line 6A which is fancifully decorated as a full-exterior ad bought by the zoo.

Line 6A does go from the city center to the zoo -- there are several stops in the city center, such as at Nørreport, Rådhuspladsen, near Vesterport in front of the "Palads" movie theater, and nearish the central station (diagonally across the intersection from Hotel Astoria to the northwest of the station). You'll want the direction with destination "Rødovrehallen".

You won't be able to get a ride in a snake-decorated bus, though. The ad campaign ran in 2010, and the involved buses have long since been returned to normal livery or other ads.